# Reading JSON File inside the Javascript adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

MFP 8, Javascript adapters should read the JSON file (TestData.json) placed in

> "\src\main\adapter-resources"

I need to read the static array contents from `json/text` file within the same `JAVASCRIPT HTTP` adapter. How to do the same ?

Read the static arrays from file (Text/JSON) within same adapter folder.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414618/reading-local-server-json-file-with-mobilefirst-javascript-adapter), you can read a JSON file with Javascript as shown below.

```
function readFile(filename) {
    var content = "";

    var fileReader = new java.io.FileReader(filename);

    var bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(fileReader);

    var line;

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        content += line;
    }   

    bufferedReader.close();

    return content;
}

function test() {
    var file = 'yourfilename.json';
    var fileContents;
    try {
         fileContents = JSON.parse(readFile(file));     
    }  catch(ex) {
        // handle error                
    }

    return  {
        fileContents: fileContents
    };
```

Comment: @Vinay Inside `js` folder located in this path `\src\main\adapter-resources`.

Comment: let say, i have multiple array variables in the same file, how to read specifically ?

Comment: Function `readFile(file)` returns the data in plain string, you can parse it however it is required.

Comment: when i added this code, its says that JSON

`{"message":"java.io.FileNotFoundException: sampleData.json (No such file or directory)`

Comment: is there any way to keep .properties file and read the content ? but the path, @vittal mentioned doesn't work